# Explain CORS in Kubernetes context

Tags: kubernetes, cross-origin-resource-policy

The following configuration has been taken out from [here](https://projectcontour.io/docs/v1.20.1/config/cors/):

```
apiVersion: projectcontour.io/v1
kind: HTTPProxy
metadata:
  name: cors-example
spec:
  virtualhost:
    fqdn: www.example.com
    corsPolicy:
        allowCredentials: true
        allowOrigin:
          - "*" # allows any origin
        allowMethods:
          - GET
          - POST
          - OPTIONS
        allowHeaders:
          - authorization
          - cache-control
        exposeHeaders:
          - Content-Length
          - Content-Range
        maxAge: "10m" # preflight requests can be cached for 10 minutes.
  routes:
    - conditions:
      - prefix: /
      services:
        - name: cors-example
          port: 80
```

My understanding is that entrance to the cluster is allowed only through `www.example.com`. Any other external url won't even hit the HTTPProxy.

- Hence, I really do not get the role of `corsPolicy`. What exactly does? What does `allows any origin` mean? **The only origin HTTPProxy allows, is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). Correct?**
- In general, are there any CORS restrictions **inside** K8s cluster (`pod to pod`)? My understanding again is `no`.

P.S. ***Please do not explain what CORS is. I know very well.This is not my question***

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/cors-tutorial-a-guide-to-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Comment: _"My understanding is that entrance to the cluster is allowed only through www.example.com. Any other external url won't even hit the HTTPProxy."_ - and what does that have to do with anything ...? CORS is not about where you are making the request _to_, but where you are making it _from_.

Comment: I think you are confusing CORS with CSP...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your overconfidence in knowing what CORS means is clouding your reasoning. Lets imagine the following scenario:

- You are hosting a REST API at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- I am a developer of [www.somewebsite.com](http://www.somewebsite.com) and I want to use your API.
- My website tries to fetch data from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

  - The above policy will tell the browser to allow me to fetch your data since I will get a response from your server with a header that allowed origins are `*`.
- If you don't include this configuration, the browser will not let me consume your API since the domain of my website [www.somewebsite.com] is not allowed to call this API and is not the same with the one where you host the API.

You see I am still trying to fetch data from your domain, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and the HTTP Proxy will hit your pods, but the browser is the one that will prevent me from getting the data, unless you have the above configuration.